# Iterating dependent dropdowns with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, drop-down-menu, web-scraping

As a Python newbie, I'm trying to scrap some data from [This Site](https://seffaflik.epias.com.tr/transparency/uretim/planlama/kgup.xhtml)

Main goal is to get data for every option to an excel file with pandas.

As a firtst step we try go get all options from dropdowns with the code below. (Python 3.6.0)

```py
import sys
import signal
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException

def sigint(signal, frame):
    sys.exit(0)

def make_waitfor_elem_updated_predicate(driver, waitfor_elem_id):
    elem = driver.find_element_by_id(waitfor_elem_id)

    def elem_updated(driver):
        try:
            elem.text
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            return True
        except:
            pass

        return False

    return lambda driver: elem_updated(driver)

class Scraper(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.url = 'https://seffaflik.epias.com.tr/transparency/uretim/planlama/kgup.xhtml'
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.maximize_window()

    def get_select(self, id):
        select_elem = self.driver.find_element_by_id(id)
        select = Select(select_elem)
        return select

    def select_option(self, id, value, waitfor_elem_id=None):
        if waitfor_elem_id:
            func = make_waitfor_elem_updated_predicate(
                self.driver, 
                waitfor_elem_id
            )

        select = self.get_select(id)
        select.select_by_value(value)

        if waitfor_elem_id:
            wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
            wait.until(func)

        return self.get_select(id)

    def make_select_option_iterator(self, id, waitfor_elem_id):
        def next_option(id, waitfor_elem_id):
            select = self.get_select(id)
            select_option_values = [ 
                '%s' % o.get_attribute('value') 
                for o 
                in select.options 
                if o.text != 'TÜMÜ'
            ]

            for v in select_option_values:
                select = self.select_option(id, v, waitfor_elem_id)
                yield select.first_selected_option.text

        return lambda: next_option(id, waitfor_elem_id)

    def load_page(self):
        self.driver.get(self.url)

        def page_loaded(driver):
            id = 'j_idt102:distributionId_input'
            return driver.find_element_by_id(id)

        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
        wait.until(page_loaded)            

    def scrape(self):
        organisations = self.make_select_option_iterator(
            'j_idt102:distributionId_input',
            'j_idt102:uevcb_input'
        )

        units = self.make_select_option_iterator(
            'j_idt102:uevcb_input',
            'j_idt102:uevcb_input'
        )


        self.load_page()

        for organisation in organisations():
            print (organisation)
            for unit in units():
                print (2*' ', unit)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, sigint)
    scraper = Scraper()
    scraper.scrape()
```

We get ids from select elements but error code says:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedTagNameException: Message: Select only works on  elements, not on
```

Any idea for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you're trying to apply class `Select` to `<div>` element, while you could use `Select` with `<select>` elements only!

Try just to handle drop-down by clicking consequently on drop-down button and then on required option, e.g.:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('j_idt102:distributionId_label').click() # opens drop-down
driver.find_element_by_id('j_idt102:distributionId_1').click() # select option
```

Comment: Then how should i iterate it for every option? Thanks.

Comment: Options in each drop-down are just a list items (`<li>`) in unordered list (`<ul>`). You can get list of options from drop-down as `drop_down = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="ui-selectonemenu-panel ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-helper-hidden ui-shadow"][contains(@style, "display: block")]')` `drop_down.find_elements_by_xpath('.//li[@class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all ui-state-highlight"]')`

Comment: Thanks a lot (again!)